# How to get a dictionary or list from <class 'py2neo.database.Record'>

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

Using py2neo to connect to neo4j DB:
How can I convert "class 'py2neo.database.Record'" to a dictionary or list in python?

Comment: Which version of py2neo are you using? And what does your query return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly convert a `Record` to a list:

```
result = graph.cypher.execute('MATCH (n) RETURN n')

a_record = result[0] # -> this is a Record object

list_of_things_in_record = list(a_record)

print(list_of_things_in_record)
```

Comment: Same applies for `dict` - you can wrap a `Record` in the function.

Comment: @NigelSmall If you were using py2neo3 with the cursor, how would you do it?

Comment: This just creates a list with a single item. That item is the record

Answer (score 1):

Seems the `data()`-Method in any `neo4j.data.Record` can convert it into a `dict`.

```
with self.driver.session() as session:
    records = session.write_transaction(self._return_nodes, cypher)
    rdict = [rec.data() for rec in records]
    return rdict


 @staticmethod
    def _return_nodes(tx, cypher):        
        return [rec for rec in tx.run(cypher)]
```